# Netty handler is not instantiater for every call

Tags: java, netty

I have a problem with new Handler() implementation. I have a class member in the handler which is initialized with a random UUID. When I look at the data, there are multiple requests with the same UUID.

```
public class HttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
   @Override
   public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
       .....
       p.addLast("httprequest", new HttpServerHandler(config));
   }
}
```

HttpServerHandler

```
private String uuid;

public HttpServerHandler(final StaticConfig staticConfig) {

    this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

}
```

This uuid is not unique for every call.

Instead if I add random_uuid to **attr** , it works fine.

So, I do have a way to fix this. The problem is that this conflicts with my understanding of how the handlers are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initChannel(...)` is called for each new connection. So if you multiple requests are send over the same connection you will see it once